flutter api error ERR_FAILED 404 (Not Found) when trying to retrieve data from my node app.js api
I am working on a app that when a user enters a cps number in the flutter app the node js api is supposed to check the database and see if there is a matching item description.
here is my flutter code
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:surplus/summary.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

class FormPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _FormPageState createState() => _FormPageState();
}

class _FormPageState extends State<FormPage> {
  List<FormData> forms = [];
  String? _selectedSchool;
final List<String> _schools = [
  'Alpha Hart Lewis Elementary',
  'Battle High School',
  'Benton Elementary',
  'Beulah Ralph Elementary',
  'Blue Ridge Elementary',
  'Business Office',
  'CORE-Boys and Girls Town',
  'CORE-Quest',
  'Cedar Ridge Elementary',
  'Center for Early Learning North',
  'Columbia Area Career Center',
  'Derby Ridge Elementary',
  'Douglass High Adult Basic Ed',
  'Douglass High School',
  'Early Childhood Discovery Cntr',
  'Early Childhood Special Ed',
  'Eliot Battle Elementary',
  'Facilities & Construction Srv',
  'Fairview Elementary',
  'Field Building',
  'Gentry Middle School',
  'Gifted Center',
  'Grant Elementary',
  'Hickman High School',
  'Jefferson Middle School',
  'John Warner Middle School',
  'Juvenile Justice Center',
  'Lange Middle School',
  'Locust Street Expressive Arts Elementary',
  'Mail Check',
  'Midway Heights Elementary',
  'Mill Creek Elementary',
  'Moving On Together',
  'New Haven Elementary',
  'Nutrition Services',
  'Oakland Middle School',
  'Park Avenue Head Start',
  'Parkade Elementary',
  'Paxton-Keeley Elementary',
  'Rainforest School',
  'Ridgeway Elementary',
  'Rock Bridge Elementary',
  'Rock Bridge High School',
  'Rosetta Avenue Learning Center',
  'Russell Blvd Elementary',
  'Shepard Blvd Elementary',
  'Smithton Middle School',
  'Two Mile Prairie Elementary',
  'West Blvd Elementary',
  'West Middle School',
];


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    forms.add(FormData());
  }

  void addNewForm() {
    setState(() {
      forms.add(FormData());
    });
  }

  void reviewData(BuildContext context) async {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => SummaryPage(
          formData: forms.where((element) => element.cpsNumber.isNotEmpty).toList(),
          school: _selectedSchool ?? "",
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Surplus Asset Disposal Form'),
          centerTitle: true,
      foregroundColor: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Color(0xFF005570), // Set text color to white

        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                value: _selectedSchool,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Select School',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedSchool = newValue;
                  });
                },
                items: _schools.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: forms.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) => MyCustomForm(
                  formData: forms[index],
                  onCpsNumberTyped: addNewForm,
                  onDataUpdated: (data) {
                    setState(() => forms[index] = data);
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () => reviewData(context),
                child: Text('REVIEW'),
              style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            foregroundColor: Colors.white, backgroundColor: Color(0xFF005570), // Set text color to white

            ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FormData {
  String cpsNumber;
  String itemDescription;
  String? selectedReason;

  FormData({
    this.cpsNumber = "",
    this.itemDescription = "",
    this.selectedReason,
  });

  FormData copyWith({String? cpsNumber, String? itemDescription, String? selectedReason}) {
    return FormData(
      cpsNumber: cpsNumber ?? this.cpsNumber,
      itemDescription: itemDescription ?? this.itemDescription,
      selectedReason: selectedReason ?? this.selectedReason,
    );
  }
}

class MyCustomForm extends StatefulWidget {
  final FormData formData;
  final VoidCallback onCpsNumberTyped;
  final Function(FormData) onDataUpdated;

  MyCustomForm({required this.formData, required this.onCpsNumberTyped, required this.onDataUpdated});

  @override
  _MyCustomFormState createState() => _MyCustomFormState();
}

class _MyCustomFormState extends State<MyCustomForm> {
  final TextEditingController _cpsNumberController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _itemDescriptionController = TextEditingController();
  String? selectedReason;
  bool _isFirstInput = true;

final List<String> _reasonsForSurplus = [
  'No Longer Used',
  'Burned Out',
  'Broken',
  'Extinction',
  'Obsolete',
];


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _cpsNumberController.text = widget.formData.cpsNumber;
    _itemDescriptionController.text = widget.formData.itemDescription;
    selectedReason = widget.formData.selectedReason;
    _cpsNumberController.addListener(() {
      final cpsNumber = _cpsNumberController.text;
      if (cpsNumber.isNotEmpty && _isFirstInput) {
        _fetchItemDescription(cpsNumber);
        widget.onCpsNumberTyped();
        _isFirstInput = false; // Prevents continuous addition of forms
      }
      widget.onDataUpdated(widget.formData.copyWith(cpsNumber: cpsNumber));
    });
    _itemDescriptionController.addListener(() {
      widget.onDataUpdated(widget.formData.copyWith(itemDescription: _itemDescriptionController.text));
    });
  }

void _fetchItemDescription(String cpsNumber) async {
  final url = Uri.parse('https://web.cpsk12.org/surplus/api/app/surplusItems?CPSNumber=$cpsNumber');
  try {
    final response = await http.get(url);
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final data = json.decode(response.body);
      if (data != null && data['Description'] != null) {
        setState(() {
          _itemDescriptionController.text = data['Description'];
          widget.onDataUpdated(widget.formData.copyWith(itemDescription: data['Description']));
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _itemDescriptionController.text = '';
          widget.onDataUpdated(widget.formData.copyWith(itemDescription: ''));
        });
      }
    } else {
      print('Server error: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  } catch (e) {
    print('Failed to fetch item description: $e');
    setState(() {
      _itemDescriptionController.text = '';
      widget.onDataUpdated(widget.formData.copyWith(itemDescription: ''));
    });
  }
}


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: <Widget>[
              TextFormField(
                controller: _cpsNumberController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'CPS Number',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                onFieldSubmitted: (value) {
                  // Trigger fetchItemDescription when Enter key is pressed
                  _fetchItemDescription(value);
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 24.0),
              TextFormField(
                controller: _itemDescriptionController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Item Description',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                maxLines: null,
              ),
              SizedBox(height: 24.0),
              DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
                value: selectedReason,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  labelText: 'Reason for Surplus',
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                ),
                onChanged: (String? newValue) {
                  setState(() {
                    selectedReason = newValue;
                    widget.onDataUpdated(widget.formData.copyWith(selectedReason: newValue));
                  });
                },
                items: _reasonsForSurplus.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                    value: value,
                    child: Text(value),
                  );
                }).toList(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _cpsNumberController.dispose();
    _itemDescriptionController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}

I have node installed on my server and did the following
and the server is running on C:\inetpub\wwwroot\surplus\api>node app.js
Server is running on port 3000
here is my app.js code
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const sql = require('mssql');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Configuration for SQL Server connection
const config = {
    user: 'dbusername',
    password: 'dbpassword',
    server: 'server', // You need to provide the server name/IP address
    database: 'databasename',
    options: {
        enableArithAbort: true // This option is required for SQL Server connection
    }
};

// Middleware to parse JSON bodies
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Set CORS headers for cross-origin allowance
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, OPTIONS");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Authorization");
    next();
});

// API endpoint for GET requests
app.get('/surplusItems', async (req, res) => {
    const CPSNumber = req.query.CPSNumber;

    if (!CPSNumber) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: "CPSNumber parameter is missing" });
    }

    try {
        await sql.connect(config);
        const result = await sql.query`SELECT Description FROM SurplusItemsNew WHERE CPSNumber = ${CPSNumber}`;
        sql.close();

        if (result.recordset.length === 0) {
            return res.status(404).json({ error: "No item found with the given CPSNumber" });
        }

        return res.json(result.recordset[0]);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error occurred:", error);
        return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
    }
});

// Start the server
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});

I am very new to node js so any help would be amazing!!!!!!
thanks in advance!!!!!
